# How do I convert a troff manpage with UTF-8 characters (czech to be precise) to PDF

Tags: pdf, unicode, conversion, groff, roff

I have a troff document (manpage) with UTF-8 characters and I am trying to convert it to a PDF. However, when using the -Tpdf option, the PDF generated does not show the correct characters. This is the command I am using:

```
groff -k -Tutf-8 -pet -Tpdf -mandoc filename.1 > filename.pdf
```

Examples of what goes wrong:

"Používá" becomes "Pou3⁄4ívá"
"překladač" becomes "pøekladaè"
"prováděných" becomes "provádìných"
"rozšířením" becomes "roz1íøením"

How to do it correctly?

Comment: Are you sure you want `-Tutf-8`? From a glance at the manual, it seems like your two `-T` options might be conflicting, and `-D` is used to select a charset

Comment: Ah, sorry, I am not sure, I was just already very desparate. Using -D utf-8 makes the problematic characters disappear completely, resulting in 'can't find special character' warnings

Comment: What about `-K utf-8`?

Comment: I'm testing things now.  Interestingly, if I use `-D utf-8` or `-K utf-8` along with `-T utf-8`, I can see the Czech symbols, but when I change `-T utf-8` to `-T ps` or `-T pdf` the problem arises.  So `grotty` acts fine with Unicode, but `grops` and `gropdf` are having trouble

Comment: See also [The Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Unicode-HOWTO-5.html) stating that `groff -Tps` is only capable of outputting the Unicode characters that "PostScript supports by itself" (though it doesn't specify which version of `groff`).  Since PDF is just compiled PostScript, this is probably the issue.

Answer (score 3):

The following convoluted way works:

```
groff -Kutf8 -Tdvi -mec -ms test.ms > test.dvi
dvipdfm -cz 9 test.dvi
open test.pdf
```

Via the [[Groff] latin2 polish special characters thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/groff/2007-09/msg00173.html) on lists.gnu.org.

Comment: For dvipdfm (or just dvipdf on some distros) you will need a texlive-basic (texlive-bin in case of Arch linux) package. dvipdfm alias calls gs and dvips which is not installed by Ghostscript.. You will need texlive for the dvips.