# How to correctly display Polish diacritic symbols in groff?

Tags: pdf, unicode, groff

I'm playing around with `groff`  and I wanted to generate a pdf from the following `test.ms`

```
.TL
Tytuł
.AU
Imię Nazwisko
.NH
Wstęp
.PP
Pierwszy paragraf. Jakieś informacje, żeby były polskie znaki.
.PP
Drugi paragraf. Reszta znaków:

ąęćłńśóżźĄĘĆŁŃŚÓŻŹ
.NH
Bla bla bla
.PP
safsdsdfsasdds
```

As you can see it contains Polish diacritic symbols. After compiling it with `groff -ms test.ms -T pdf > test.pdf` we are presented with this mess:
[image: Horrible!]

My first guess was recompiling with utf-8 support.

```
$ groff -Kutf8 -ms test.ms -T pdf > test.pdf
test.ms:4: warning: can't find special character `u0065_0328'
test.ms:8: warning: can't find special character `u0073_0301'
test.ms:8: warning: can't find special character `u00A0'
test.ms:8: warning: can't find special character `u007A_0307'
test.ms:12: warning: can't find special character `u0061_0328'
test.ms:12: warning: can't find special character `u006E_0301'
test.ms:12: warning: can't find special character `u007A_0301'
test.ms:12: warning: can't find special character `u0041_0328'
test.ms:12: warning: can't find special character `u0045_0328'
test.ms:12: warning: can't find special character `u004E_0301'
test.ms:12: warning: can't find special character `u0053_0301'
test.ms:12: warning: can't find special character `u005A_0307'
test.ms:12: warning: can't find special character `u005A_0301'
```

Groff just ignored most of the symbols and the pdf looks like this:

[image: Still awful.]

After a bit of googling I've found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361274/how-do-i-convert-a-troff-manpage-with-utf-8-characters-czech-to-be-precise-to):

```
groff -Kutf8 -Tdvi -mec -ms test.ms > test.dvi
dvipdfm -cz 9 test.dvi
```

Yeah, it still fails (although it's better, only one character skipped):

```
$ groff -Kutf8 -Tdvi -mec -ms test.ms > test.dvi
test.ms:8: warning: can't find special character `u00A0'
```

How can I get this to work?

**EDIT:** Here's the output of `locale`

```
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What's the output of `locale`?

Comment: @David Added the output.

Comment: Shooting in the dark: does the character font used provide the polish characters?

Comment: @RudiC I have no idea, is there a way to check it?

Comment: If you run `nroff -ms test.ms` and look at the output in a terminal emulator, are there any errors?

Comment: @atmostmediocre `locale` looks fine. Are you sure your input file uses correct encoding? Try running `file -i test.ms`, should be some encoding of Unicode.

Comment: @David Here's the output: `test.ms: text/troff; charset=utf-8`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `nroff -ms test.ms` gives incorrect output. However, `preconv test.ms | nroff -ms` is not malformed and does the same as `groff -Kutf8 -ms test.ms -Tutf8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character `A0` is an unbreakable space. It looks like it is between "Jakieś" and "informacje". Use your editor to replace it by a normal space and you should be good to go.

Advice: I've set up my editors (emacs, vim) to highlight unbreakable spaces because I sometimes unintentionally type some with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> when I hit <kbd>space</kbd> after typing a character requiring to press <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

The warnings after your first guess seem to show that some chars (ę, ś, ż...) are encoded with combining diacritics rather than natively. E.g. ę == e (hex 65) + combining ogonek (hex 328) rather than "e with ogonek" (hex 119). How do you edit your source file? You may use a Compose key to produce "standalone" letters-with-diacritics, e.g. <kbd>Compose</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> for "ę".

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be due to an outdated version of `groff`.

See [this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/354095/30290).